# Cant deploy Module not found on vercel, and cant npm run buid

Tags: reactjs, web, deployment, vercel

Module not found on vercel, and cant npm run buid[[[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9x5u.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Haiwy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lELOC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gApk6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKlN6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58McE.png)

Module not found and cant npm run build, even i already import the file

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Before asking question, it may be beneficial to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the various pages in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), particularly [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.